# When should I close an SQLite database on Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

OK, I've been trying to track down all the resources my app leaks.  One of the things I've been opening and not closing has been database handles, usually opened through getWritableDatabase() and getReadableDatabase().

Now, its usually easy to close the database after a write, but read operations are usually returning a Cursor.  I doubt its legal to close a database handle with an open Cursor.  And I certainly don't want to return both a Cursor and the database handle so that I can close them both.  Does closing the Cursor automatically close the database handle?

I looked here:  http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

But that seems to close the database handles almost at random, or wherever it seems convenient.

When and where do I close this stuff?

Comment: "When should I close an SQLite database on Android?" -- frequently, the answer is "never", because you do not know when it is a safe time to close the database. If you happen to be using the database from just one component (e.g., one `Activity`), close the database when the component is destroyed.

Comment: you can create a interface as well, that uses the cursor and returns the data in list form to the requesting activity and after the list to be returned is generated close the cursor